# INSERT INTO with subquery and ON CONFLICT

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert, upsert, on-clause

I want to insert all elements from a JSON array into a table:

```sql
INSERT INTO local_config(parameter, value)
SELECT json_extract(j.value, '$.parameter'), json_extract(j.value, '$.value')
FROM json_each(json('[{"parameter": 1, "value": "value1"}, {"parameter": 2, "value": "value2"}]')) AS j
WHERE value LIKE '%'
ON CONFLICT (parameter) DO UPDATE SET value = excluded.value;
```

This works so far, but do I really need the `WHERE value LIKE '%'` clause?

When I remove it:

```sql
INSERT INTO local_config(parameter, value)
SELECT json_extract(j.value, '$.parameter'), json_extract(j.value, '$.value')
FROM json_each(json('[{"parameter": 1, "value": "value1"}, {"parameter": 2, "value": "value2"}]')) AS j
ON CONFLICT (parameter) DO UPDATE SET value = excluded.value;
```

I get this error:

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "DO": syntax error)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [SQL As Understood By SQLite/Parsing Ambiguity](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

> When the INSERT statement to which the UPSERT is attached takes its
> values from a SELECT statement, there is a potential parsing
> ambiguity. The parser might not be able to tell if the "ON" keyword is
> introducing the UPSERT or if it is the ON clause of a join. To work
> around this, the SELECT statement should always include a WHERE
> clause, even if that WHERE clause is just "WHERE true".

So you need the WHERE clause, but it can be a simple `WHERE true` or just `WHERE 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was lost on this for a while...

Comment: This works but should be part of the underlying library to insert this logic